# How does Python's list.remove(value) determine what value to remove?

Tags: python, list, memory, python-internals

If I have list of objects:

```
l = [a, b, c]
```

Then I remove one of those objects:

```
l.remove(a)
```

How is python determining which item in the list to remove (under the hood)?

Is it using the memory location of `a`? (which you can view with `hex(id(a))`)

Comment: There’s no way to guess an item’s position in the list just from the value. The position completely depends on where you put the item in the first place. A set on the other hand uses a hash to determine item membership—but it will give you neither an order nor the possibilty to have multiple occurrences of the same item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It iterates through the list, compares every item with the item to be removed and if it finds a match, it just removes that. It works in O(N). Source: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity
2. It removes only the first matched item and returns immediately.
3. If the item to be removed is not there, it fails with `ValueError`

This is the [`listremove`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/13a505260f17/Objects/listobject.c#l2192) function which removes the item from a list and it uses `PyObject_RichCompareBool` to check if the items are the same. And [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/13a505260f17/Objects/object.c#l709) is implemented like this

```
/* Quick result when objects are the same.
   Guarantees that identity implies equality. */
if (v == w) {
    if (op == Py_EQ)
        return 1;
    else if (op == Py_NE)
        return 0;
}

res = PyObject_RichCompare(v, w, op);
```

If the identity of the objects are the same (if both the objects are the same), then return `1` otherwise compare the values and return the result.

Answer (score 4):

Python uses the equality test `==`. The `remove` method is similar to the following function:

```
def list_remove(a, el):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] == el:
            del a[i]
            return
    raise ValueError("item not found")
```

Comment: Actually, I think it compares identity first, falling back on `__eq__` if that test turns our False ...

Comment: @mgilson: I think you're right.  `nan = float("nan"); a = [nan]; a.remove(nan)` works even though `nan != nan`.

Comment: @DSM -- Yeah.  The real unfortunate thing is that `float('nan')` isn't a singleton.  I used a class with `__eq__ = lambda self, other: False`, but it's the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

1. if the class of the member object in the list defines the `__eq__()` method or the `__cmp__()` method, it will invoke this method to compare.
2. if not customize the comparison method, then Non-identical instances of a class normally compare as non-equal. it means the object address is used to compare.